# Runetime Compilation CSharp. Is it possible to access main program's fields from the runetime code?

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public int xx = 1; // variable I want to access from the runtime code

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");


            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, GetCode());
            var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Program");
            var method = cls.GetMethod("DynamicMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            method.Invoke(null, null);

            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // pause console
        }       


        static string[] GetCode()
        {
            return new string[]
            {
            @"using System;

            namespace ConsoleApplication1
            {
                class Program
                {
                    public static void DynamicMethod()
                    {                        
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, world!"");
                    }
                }
            }"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if It's possible to access variable **int xx** from the runetime code (eg. putting xx = 2; line after "hello world". That would be awesome
Thanks :)

Comment: There is no `int xx`. `xx` is an instance field, but there is no instance of your class `Program`. At the very least, you would need to make it a `static` field. Also, it's very confusing that your `ConsoleApplication1.Program` creates another `ConsoleApplication1.Program` class. They have the same namespace and name, but are nevertheless distinct types. Your second `ConsoleApplication1.Program` does not have the fields of the first.

Comment: @hvd or make an instance of `Program` available to the dynamic code in some way

Comment: mind any1 showing me an easy example of how should this look like? :P I've tried to change int xx into a static field, changing runtime class name into Program2 and then changing Program.xx value into 3 in runtime code but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make that available, but you need to:

- add a reference to the assembly that contains `xx` (I'm calling this assembly `StaticAssembly`, for convenience - so it is probably `StaticAssembly.exe`, the console exe that is running)
- make `Program` in `StaticAssembly` a `public` type so that it is accessible
- either make `xx` into a `static` field, or instantiate an instance of `Program` and pass it to the dynamic code somehow

The following works, for example (I'm using the "instantiate an instance and pass it" approach, so I've added a parameter to `DynamicMethod`):

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;


namespace StaticAssembly
{
    public class Program
    {
        public int xx = 1; // variable I want to access from the runtime code

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("StaticAssembly.exe");

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, GetCode());
            var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("GeneratedAssembly.Program");
            var method = cls.GetMethod("DynamicMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            var p = new Program();
            p.xx = 42;
            method.Invoke(null, new object[] {p});

            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // pause console
        }


        static string[] GetCode()
        {
            return new string[]
            {
            @"using System;

            namespace GeneratedAssembly
            {
                class Program
                {
                    public static void DynamicMethod(StaticAssembly.Program p)
                    {                        
                        Console.WriteLine(p.xx);
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, world!"");
                    }
                }
            }"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please show me the way to do that in this way?: 
"make Program in StaticAssembly a public type so that it is accessible"?

Comment: theres an error in your example 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\Arbuz\AppData\Local\Temp\ulmdtb2g.dll' or one of its dependencies.' in this line 'var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("GeneratedAssembly.Program");'

Comment: @Patryk that probably means your static assembly is not "StaticAssembly.exe". Check the `results.Errors` for more info.

Comment: @Patryk re "public type" - see in my example I added the `public` keyword to `StaticAssembly.Program` ?